# Проблема галочки

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, принятые-ответы

Галочка не срабатывает, вроде кто задавал вопрос, говорит поставил галочку, но я ее не вижу.
Как такое может  быть?
вот пример:
[работа с массивами, помогите сортировку сделать!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/620781/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

это уже второй раз, первый раз кто задавал вопрос, убрал галочку, и поставил вновь, тогда я ее увидел

Comment: Скорее всего топикастер перепутал Vote Up и отметку о принятии решения. Не заморачивайтесь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если посмотреть [историю репутации автора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/11397/dimastik86?tab=reputation) упомянутого вопроса, то там нет строки с принятием ответа:

> [image: репа]

При принятии ответа ему должны были упасть +2 в репу.

Дополнительно можно посмотреть [временную шкалу вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/620781/timeline), там тоже не видно, чтобы автор принял Ваш ответ:

> [image: шкала]

Так что, видимо ТС Вас просто вводит в заблуждение.

Comment: зачем ему это, это уже второй раз, что так у меня происходит

Comment: @L.Vadim ну попросите его предоставить скриншот с галочкой :) Но он и тут может отфотошопить. Может быть он под "принятием ответа" понял всего лишь голосование в плюс. Пока же по всем доступным каналам видно, что ТС Ваш ответ **не принял**.

Comment: у него уже есть вопросы, все он прекрасно знает. я уверен что есть какой то, баг. он сделал +1 и потом поставил галочку

Comment: @L.Vadim о баге можно будет говорить, когда будет какое-то подтверждение наличия галочки у ответа на экране монитора ТС. Пока что никаких подтверждений, кроме заявления ТС в комментарии, которое может быть интерпретировано совсем не так как Вы ожидаете, нет. Вот если бы изменение репутации у ТС было, или во временной шкале какое-то отражение, а Вы при этом не получили +15, то можно было бы говорить о баге. А так, извините, я не вижу тут бага, только человеческий фактор.

Comment: подождем когда он вернется, уберет галочку и поставит вновь